# Mobile cross platform for tuner app

Tags: android

I'm actually doing my thesis right now, and I started doing it in unity 3d platform. What i'm doing is something to do with tuning music instrument. A drum tuner to be exact. So I need to use the microphone as a real-time listener just like the guitar tuners are (guitar tuna is my benchmark). But the forums and its manual says that the class microphone is only for recording and unity is not made for such app.

Is there anybody here tried something like my thesis app (or any tuning device)? what platform should i use? Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: I have some guesses as to what you want to do, but to get any help you need to be much more specific.  What is it you're trying to do- frequency analysis of a drum tap to get it to match, like tuning a guitar string?  Something else?

Comment: Sorry sir. @GabeSechan ahhmmm i'm trying to do a drum tuner where the microphone plays as a medium for getting the frequency. For example: a guitar strings has a different sounds. Then I play the first string (which is at the bottom), then the app will determined whether the string is out of tune or not.

I can't explain it very well but please try to install guitar tuna, it's exactly what i'm saying haha thank you sir